# "When {you're signing up|sign up}, you choose your native language and country..."

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

I recently posted an entry on Lang-8 where I wrote about their new app, HiNative. Here is a sentence from that entry:

> When **you're signing up**, you choose your native language and country and your language of study and country of interest.

A native speaker corrected this to:

> When **you sign up**, you choose your native language and country, and your language of study and country of interest.

I thought that by using the progressive tense I would emphasize the process of signing up. Why can't I use *you're signing up*, and is there a difference in meaning between the two sentences?

Comment: The present continuous "Signing up" is perfectly idiomatic in that sentence. Why do you think the person who corrected you is a native speaker? My guess is that the person is not. Remember: _"On the internet, no-one knows you're a dog."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are times when you'd want to use the progressive and times when sign-up is treated as a point-in-time event and so you'd use the simple tense.

It's really a matter of how you perceive the time of the action (or how the person correcting you is perceiving the time of the action).

> You choose your native language and country **at sign-up**.  
>   <sup>point-in-time</sup>
>
> You choose your native language and country **when you sign up**. 
>     <sup>point-in-time</sup>

If one understands the choice of language and country to be something that happens not  when you're using the site and decide to update your profile, but **at** sign-up time, then the simple present seems the better choice. It doesn't happen later on, it happens at the time of sign-up. The underlying temporal concept is a time-line.

> **When I was signing up**, the system froze when I clicked the Submit button.<sup>a process is progressing</sup>

The system freezing was something that happened when the sign-up process was *underway*.

Whether you perceive the sign-up as a point on a time-line or as a process is up to you.